# How to find the lowest and highest values on a regression line with R?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have data similar to this:

```
sample <- read.table(text =
                       "   value    date
                           -5.4     2017-03-01
                            -2.2    2017-03-05
                           -1.1    2017-03-10
                           4.9      2017-03-12
                           4.8      2017-03-22
                           5.6      2017-04-02
                           -0.3     2017-04-11
                           0.6      2017-04-16
                           3.3     2017-04-20
                           5.2      2017-04-22  ", header = T)
sample$date = as.Date(sample$date)
```

I made a plot with these values with linear regression trend:

```
plot(sample$date,sample$value)
abline(lm(sample$value ~ sample$date))
```

[image]

I would like to find difference between lowest and highest 'value' from regression line. I marked those points with red on the plot.

How to do that in R?

My idea is to somehow make a column of values on the regression line corresponding each date of my dataset, but I struggle to do that.

Comment: No, I marked them manually for better explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be as straightforward as this (I've renamed your data frame to `SAMPLE` and dropped `$` from the model formula):

```
fit <- lm(value ~ date, data = SAMPLE)
diff(range(fit$fitted))
```

> My idea is to somehow make a column of values on the regression line corresponding each date of my dataset, but I struggle to do that.

The column you want is called "fitted values" and `lm` returns it.

---

**Remark 1**

The above result is always some positive value regardless an ascending or descending line, because `range` returns `min` before `max`. You can adjust that by the sign of the slope so that it is positive for an ascending line and negative for a descending line.

```
diff(range(fit$fitted)) * sign(fit$coef[2])
```

**Remark 2**

As Maurits Evers comments, you can also use `predict(fit)` than `fit$fitted`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
 fit <- lm(value ~ date, data = sample)

 sample%>%
   arrange(desc(date))%>%
   mutate(prd=map_dbl( sample$date,~predict (fit,newdata=data.frame(date=.x))))%>%
   summarise(max(prd)-min(prd))%>%as.numeric()

[1] 5.133998
```